# Does task scheduling in Lumen work just like in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, scheduled-tasks, laravel-5.1, lumen

You can see [task scheduling](http://laravel.com/docs/master/scheduling) explained in the latest docs for Laravel, but Lumen's docs do not mention this. However, it looks like [Lumen's Console Kernel file](https://github.com/laravel/lumen/blob/master/app/Console/Kernel.php) has a schedule method just like Laravel. Does scheduling work the same in both, or what are the caveats with scheduling in Lumen?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yes, yes it does! :) It works exactly the same.

```
crontab -e
```

And then add

```
* * * * * php /var/www/domain.com/public_html/artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Come to think of it, the `php artisan schedule:run` kinda gives it away :p