# Lumen task scheduling everyMinute isn't working?

Tags: php, laravel, cron, lumen

I have setup a command that generates a `PDF` with some stats and it sends the `pdf` as an attachment in an email. The command works great when I run t manually in my console.

```
php artisan send:report
```

Now I am trying to setup that this command is executed every last day of the month. To test I have setup the scheduler to `everyMinute` but when I run `php artisan schedule:run` the email is sent only 1 time when I run the command and not every minute.

Am I doing something wrong here?

My Kernel.php file in Lumen

```
<?php

namespace App\Console;

use App\Console\Commands\SendReport;
use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Laravel\Lumen\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $commands = [
        SendReport::class,
    ];

    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command('report:send')->everyMinute();
    }
}
```

Am I missing something ?

Any help is greatly appreciated !

Many thanks in advance !

Comment: Can you add command action code as well ?

Comment: @Sagar The command works, I tested it by running it manualy php artisan report:send. But I think the problem is I haven't setup a cronjob to run the schedule

Comment: @FrankLucas Yes, that is the problem.

Comment: In server where you host, You have to configure cron job

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to set the entry in the crontab. See here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/scheduling  and scroll down to Starting The Scheduler.

Comment: Please check whether there is any error in log directory inside the laravel storage directory.

Answer (score 3):

Please ensure this is on your server Cron entries as described in the docs

```
* * * * * php /path-to-your-project/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to add a cronjob to run the schedule:run command:

Found answer in [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33356416/does-task-scheduling-in-lumen-work-just-like-in-laravel).